# FrameLayout not visible

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a problem. I want to create 3 FrameLayouts below each other, so I created this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#071c3f"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ActionBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/LayoutContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ToolBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But this only shows the first 2 FrameLayouts and the thirth FrameLayout isn't visible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your 2nd view is taking up all the remaining screen space (it's using "match_parent") after the first FrameLayout has been placed.

It looks like you're wanting a fixed header and footer along with a content view that fills the remaining space.  So, if that assumption is true, I think this is what you are after...notice the usage of the "layout_weight" attribute and how the content view is assigned a "1" whereas the others are assigned a "0"...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#071c3f"
              android:orientation="vertical">
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ActionBarContainer"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height = "75dp"
    android:layout_weight = "0"/>
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/LayoutContainer"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight = "1"/>
  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ToolBarContainer"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"    
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight = "0"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
  <color name="blue">#ff0000ff</color>
  <color name="green">#ff00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Hope this helps!